# Order custom taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have some custom taxonomy for regions.

Commonly it would look something like this.

```
USA (parent)
- Arizona (child 1)
- - Phoenix (child 2)
```

however, there will be cases where it will only be like

```
USA
- Arizona
```

or

```
UK
- Wales
```

and maybe even just

```
Japan
```

In my for loop I get the taxonomy data as `$location = get_the_terms( $id, 'listings_region' );`

and then in the html/php I can simply write `$location[0]->name` and then I get the the name of the first object in the array.

I have however noticed that the taxonomy comes back not in the correct hierarchy - instead, alphabetically.

When I `echo '<pre>'; print_r($location); echo '</pre>'`, I get the array and [0] would be Arizona and [1] would be USA.

How can I retrieve it the taxonomy array in the correct order so that ideally [0] is always the parent, [1] is the first child, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working,

```
$location = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'listings_region', array('orderby'=> 'parent'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I basically understand that you want to display all the categories with corresponding child-categories. You can do this by following code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($id, 'listings_region');
foreach($terms as $key => $term){
    if($term->parent != 0){
        $terms[$term->parent]->children[] = $term;
        unset($terms[$key]);
    }
}
```

Not tested own so you need to print it once to get it your way but, need to change approach to access the category and it's child.

Comment: please accept answer if code helps you and let other, in future looking for same solution.